# in vb.net how do I use a variable in a variable name

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have a bunch of variables named "panel_1", panel_2", etc and I want to change the height of all of the controls using a loop rather than naming each one.

Currently I use

```
Dim panel_1 as new panel
Dim panel_2 as new panel
Dim panel_3 as new panel

panel_1.height = 100
panel_2.height = 100
panel_3.height = 100
```

How can I do it this way?

```
for x as integer = 0 to 1000
  panel_[x].height = 100
next
```

thanks.

Comment: Is this a WinForm project?  WPF, ASP.NET, other?

Comment: Keep them in an array together or else loop over the controls collection: `For Each pnl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of panel)()`, but only if you can guarantee that these are the only `panel`s in the collection.

Comment: ...or store the names in a List(of String) and then step thru that as in index into the Controls collection

Comment: BTW, no one said it but do yourself a favor--come up with better names than "panel_n".  Code using names of that sort becomes really hard to read in a few months.

Comment: That is not their real names, I just used it for the ease of this example. (no one probably said it for a reason ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a WinForm project, all of the controls are included in the form's `Controls` collection, which is accessible by name, like this:

```
For x As Integer = 0 to 1000
    Me.Controls("panel_" & i.ToString()).height = 100
Next
```

However, be aware that the form's `Controls` collection only contains the controls that are added directly to the form.  If you have controls that are inside another container control, you will need to access them through that container's `Controls` property, for instance:

```
For x As Integer = 0 to 1000
    MyContainer.Controls("panel_" & i.ToString()).height = 100
Next
```

However, accessing controls by their string name may be something that you wish to avoid, since it can lead to unintended consequences down the road.  As other's have suggested, it may be better to store the list of panels in a List(Of Panel) variable, which only contains the specific panel controls to which the resizing logic applies, like this:

```
Dim autoResizePanels As New List(Of Panel)({panel1, panel2, panel3})
```

Then, you can loop through them easily, like this:

```
For Each i As Panel In autoResizePanels 
    i.height = 100
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, It is a winForms project. So I have to access them through their parent and I can't just access them directly? That's fine. I'll do it that way. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for controls, that's the best way to do it.  For other kinds of properties, you would likely need to resort to *Reflection*, but usually you want to save *Reflection* for last-resort situations.

Comment: The list seems like a good idea, but all of the controls are created dynamically so I don't know how many their will be in the end.

Comment: You don't need to know how many there will be in the end.  Just add them to the list as they are dynamically created (e.g. `autoResizePanels.Add(thePanelIJustCreated)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such variable access in VB.NET.

Instead of defining three variables, define an array or list

```
Dim panels as new List(Of Panel)
panels.Add(new Panel())
panels.Add(new Panel())

for x as integer = 0 to 1000
  Dim p as new Panel
  p.height = 100
  panels.Add(p)

  panels(x).width = 150
next
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use an array in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to (usually) store the controls names:

```
Dim panels as new List(Of String)

For n As integer = 0 to X
   Dim pnl As New Panel
   '... set values
   panels.Add(pnl.Name)
   Controls.Add(pnl)
Next n
```

To reference one:

```
Controls(panels(IndexofOneYouWant).Height = 100
```

Since you dynamically created the control, you could also be deleting them on occasion.  In that case the List is not holding a reference to them when you go to remove one.  If they remain once created, then a `List(of Panel)` is easier and better.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through how many panels you want (In your case 3) & create a new panel on each iteration, setting the height & name programmatically.

```
For i = 0 To 3
  Dim panel As New Panel
  panel.Name = "panel" & i
  panel.Height = 100
Next
```

Comment: In this example i have created the panels within the loop. However if you wanted to change the height of the 3 variables you have defined, you wouldn't be able to do it without them being in a collection/array.